# how to use {{data.date}} with timeago? Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to use timeago.js with AngularJS.
If I place the date at the abbr title it works
But if i use {{data.commented_at}} instead, it does not works.
I am loading timeago at document.ready jquery function.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Its considers bad practice to use Angular and jQuery together for the most part, although there are exceptions. But also please supply some code to show us what you have tried already. a JSFiddle is always nice. You will get a much better response from the community if you put more effort into your question.

Comment: there are angular modules for timeago and using `document.ready` in angular app is fairly useless. Any jQuery plugins should be initialized in directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jsfiddle has its own timeago filter so you don't have to include the  jquery library instead just use this filter.

http://jsfiddle.net/i_woody/cnL5T/

Filter Code:

```
angular.module('yourmodule', []).filter('timeago', function() {
        return function(input, p_allowFuture) {
            var substitute = function (stringOrFunction, number, strings) {
                    var string =  (typeof stringOrFunction === "function") ? stringOrFunction(number, dateDifference) : stringOrFunction;
                    var value = (strings.numbers && strings.numbers[number]) || number;
                    return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
                },
                nowTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
                date = (new Date(input)).getTime(),
                //refreshMillis= 6e4, //A minute
                allowFuture = p_allowFuture || false,
                strings= {
                    prefixAgo: null,
                    prefixFromNow: null,
                    suffixAgo: "ago",
                    suffixFromNow: "from now",
                    seconds: "less than a minute",
                    minute: "about a minute",
                    minutes: "%d minutes",
                    hour: "about an hour",
                    hours: "about %d hours",
                    day: "a day",
                    days: "%d days",
                    month: "about a month",
                    months: "%d months",
                    year: "about a year",
                    years: "%d years"
                },
                dateDifference = nowTime - date,
                words,
                seconds = Math.abs(dateDifference) / 1000,
                minutes = seconds / 60,
                hours = minutes / 60,
                days = hours / 24,
                years = days / 365,
                separator = strings.wordSeparator === undefined ?  " " : strings.wordSeparator,

                // var strings = this.settings.strings;
                prefix = strings.prefixAgo,
                suffix = strings.suffixAgo;

            if (allowFuture) {
                if (dateDifference < 0) {
                    prefix = strings.prefixFromNow;
                    suffix = strings.suffixFromNow;
                }
            }

            words = seconds < 45 && substitute(strings.seconds, Math.round(seconds), strings) ||
            seconds < 90 && substitute(strings.minute, 1, strings) ||
            minutes < 45 && substitute(strings.minutes, Math.round(minutes), strings) ||
            minutes < 90 && substitute(strings.hour, 1, strings) ||
            hours < 24 && substitute(strings.hours, Math.round(hours), strings) ||
            hours < 42 && substitute(strings.day, 1, strings) ||
            days < 30 && substitute(strings.days, Math.round(days), strings) ||
            days < 45 && substitute(strings.month, 1, strings) ||
            days < 365 && substitute(strings.months, Math.round(days / 30), strings) ||
            years < 1.5 && substitute(strings.year, 1, strings) ||
            substitute(strings.years, Math.round(years), strings);

            return [prefix, words, suffix].join(separator).trim();
            // conditional based on optional argument
            // if (somethingElse) {
            //     out = out.toUpperCase();
            // }
            // return out;
        }
    });
```

Comment: does still have jQuery dependencies in it...not complaining but just mentioning it

Comment: edited and removed the jquery dependencies. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Timeago is a jQuery plugin which turns all abbr elements with a class of timeago and an ISO 8601 timestamp in the title to something like this "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago".

So it requires your html element to be abbr with the class timeago. 
I hope you are following this with angular. 
So with angular it should be ::

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="commented_at">December 17, 2011</abbr>
```

**commented_at** should be a property of scope.

Comment: yes, it is. as I've said, without angular  bind, it works fine. but when i put {{commented_at}}, it doest not works